# No mouse options in "Mouse & touchpad" panel

Tags: mouse, gnome-control-center

I've recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 (new install). The control panel "Mouse & Touchpad" has only two options: "Primary button" and "Double-click". Google shows me that other users have much more options in this panel. What can I do to make them available?

I'm currenty using Microsoft Comfort mouse 4500.

Comment: I think i have the same problem, please report your problem here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1132063

Comment: oh man, i have the same problem on ubuntu 16.04. The "mouse&touchpad" just has no option to set the wireless mouse speed.